# Merge rows in a specific order

Tags: python, merge, concatenation

**Nevermind the new dataset gave NaNs because it did not contain fitting data**

I have a before and after survey and I want to create a dataset with rows containing all the results of one person. How do I concat the two dataframes making sure it takes the column 'Full name' as a reference point when it comes ordering the rows? Thank you!

```
concatenated = pd.concat([df, data], axis=1)
```

I tried this line of Python code but it does not order the rows.

Comment: I think you want to _merge_ the dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this helps you:

```py
import pandas as pd
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'last_name': {0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three"},
                   'first_name': {0: "four", 1: "five", 2: "six"}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'last_name': {0: "one", 1: "two", 2: "three"},
                   'Value1': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 16},
                   'Value2': {0: 27, 1: 23, 2: 21},
                   'Value3': {0: 43, 1: 33, 2: 17}})
print(df1)

print(df2)

final_df = df1.merge(df2, on='last_name', how='left')
final_df
```

output:

[image]

if you want `concat`, you can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: "first", 1: "second", 2: "third"},
                   'first_name': {0: "four", 1: "five", 2: "six"}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: "forth", 1: "fifth", 2: "sixth"},
                   'first_name': {0: "seve", 1: "eight", 2: "nine"}})

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2,], axis=0)


final_df
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I tried this `final_df = df.merge(data, on='Full name', how='left')`. However, the merged columns contain only NaNs

Comment: @A.L.Waterman, can you edit the question and send your dataframe

Comment: unfortunately, the dataset is confidential. Can the problem be the fact that there are some other columns with the same name (e.g. timestamp) but different data?

Comment: @A.L.Waterman, I edit the post and add a code block, is this your answer?

Comment: I tested it with other datasets and then your code worked. Hence, it was the dataset I used that was faulty. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use merge instead of concat. Merge allows you to order you desired output according to your choice

```
pandas.merge_ordered(left, right, on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, left_by=None, right_by=None, fill_method=None, suffixes=('_x', '_y'), how='outer')
```

where the parameter means:
**Parameters

```
left = DataFrame
right =DataFrame
on   =label or list
```

fields on which you want to join on(Must be in both DataFrames)

```
left_on =label or list
right_on=label or listleft_on docs.
left_by=column name or list of column names
right_by=column name or list of column names
fill_method={‘ffill’, None}, default None
suffixes =list-like,default is (“_x”, “_y”)
how={‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’}, default ‘outer’
```